# Derivative of any $x$ which is not zero.

Tags: calculus

I'm studying derivatives and came across this example. The exercise doesn't mention if x is a constant or any function. As mentions that x is different from zero. 
Why the derivative that x is not zero but is 1, (x)' = 1?

$$
g(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}, x \neq 0 \\
g'(x) = \dfrac{(1)'x - 1(x)'}{x^2} = \dfrac{0.x - 1.1}{x^2} = \dfrac{-1}{x^2}
$$

Comment: In this question $x$ is a variable, and you are expected to differentiate with respect to this variable. It is not (explicitly) a function of any other variable, and it is not constant. It is explicitly mentioned that $x\neq0$ because the expression $\tfrac{1}{x}$ is not defined for $x=0$.

Comment: It isn't clear (to me at least) what you are asking.  Are you asking why $x'=1$?

Comment: Are you studying these on your own? You shouldn't.

Comment: @lulu Yes. This is my question.

Comment: I second the comment from @BolzWeir .  This material is not intuitive and it really helps to have someone to check your understanding,

Comment: $g'(x)$ inplies taking a derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: @DanielaMorais Ok.  Well, informally $x'$ means the rate of change of $x$ with respect to $x$.  For finite changes we clearly have $\frac {\Delta x}{\Delta x} = 1$ and the derivative is just the limit of this expression as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Let $f\left(x\right)=x$. Now $$\lim_{\Delta h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f\left(x+\Delta h\right)-f\left(x\right)}{\Delta h}=\lim_{\Delta h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left(x+\Delta h\right)-x}{\Delta h}=\lim_{\Delta h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta h}{\Delta h}=1.$$ This is why, by the definition of derivative, we know that $f'\left(x\right)=1$.

Comment: As an exercise, look at the function $h(x)=mx+b$ for real constants $m,b$.  Convince yourself that $h'(x)=m$.  That is, the derivative generalizes the simpler notion of slope.

Comment: contrary to some comments above, many thumbs up to you @DanielaMorais on learning these things on your own (if that is what you do). Learning to cope with written material on your own is something you should start doing very early on, no matter how unintuitive the stuff is. By all means, do continue to tackle anything that comes your way in any way that you see fit.

Comment: @IttayWeiss: I vehemently disagree. Have you taught any high school students before?

Comment: I think it could work. Asking a question here is a case of *not* studying these on her own. Might take longer, but there's a decent chance that her eventual understanding would surpass the results of guided study.

Comment: @DanielaMorais: Before you go further, however, you should be very certain you understand what a function of one variable is.  Continuing without a solid understanding of that will only lead to misconceptions.

Comment: I did not understand the discussion but I'm a student of Computer Science and I will have exam of calculus (derivative and applications) tomorrow. I found this example in the book which left me in doubt. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It seems you have a deep-seated misunderstanding about how derivatives work.

Answer (score 1):

Using, as $h \to 0$,
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \to f'(x).
$$

- Case $1$. $f(x)=x$, then, as $h \to 0$,

  > $$
  >    \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{(x+h)-x}{h}=\frac{h}{h} \to 1, $$ and
  >   $f'(x)=1$.
- Case $2$. $f(x)=c$, $c$ is a constant, thus $f(x+h)=c$, then, as $h
     \to 0$,

  > $$ \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{c-c}{h}=\frac0{h} \to 0, $$
  >   and $f'(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can use the power rule and not merely the quotient rule:

$$ g(x) = \frac{1}{x} = x^{-1} $$

If $ g(x) = cx^{n} $, then $ g'(x) = cnx^{n-1} $

Therefore $ g'(x) = -1 * x^{-2} = \dfrac{-1}{x^{2}} $

If x is a function f(x), then you must use the chain rule.
If x is a variable, the above is correct.
If x is a constant, then g(x) is a constant and its derivative is 0.